# Cypress.IO support for JSONP

Tags: jsonp, cypress

I've been able to use the following successfully with **XHR** Requests:

```
cy.server();
cy.route('GET','**/foo').as('bar');
//trigger ui event that make xhr GET request
cy.wait('@bar');
//happily proceed...
```

However, if I apply the same logic above, but to a **JSONP** Network Request, then `cy.wait(...)` will eventually time out.

The application I am testing sends jsonp requests.  Using cypress.io, I would like to register these requests with the intent of waiting for a response using something like `cy.wait`. Does cypress.io provide any support for jsonp requests?